How to execute a function before key press?
I'm trying to append "" to everything I write as a challenge to live a week with that enabled. It's quite easy to send "" after the fact with the keyboard module, but what I want to achieve is sending it before I press the enter key.
Here's my current code:
# it still sends it after the enter keypress
import keyboard


def on_enter_press(event):
    if event.name == "enter":
        keyboard.block_key("enter")

        keyboard.write("")

        keyboard.unhook_all()
        keyboard.press_and_release("enter")


keyboard.hook_key("enter", on_enter_press)

keyboard.wait("esc")


When do you want it to be sent? if not enter you need to have some other indicator.

Did you try putting keyboard.write('') before keyboard.block_key('enter')? Also make sure to use consistent quotation marks to avoid getting edited by others.

@Maksiks you still have one single quotes left ;)

On Windows only, you can use suppress=True in many keyboard functions to suppress the original enter press before re-sending it-- the following code works on my machine:
import keyboard

def on_enter_press():
    keyboard.write("", exact=True)
    keyboard.press_and_release("enter")

keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', on_enter_press, suppress=True)


This works flawlessly. I tried using supress=True with keyboard.read_key but I wasn't able to get it to work properly, you did though. Thanks!

To achieve the goal of appending "" before the Enter key is pressed, you'll need to modify your script so that the emoji sequence is written to the input field before the Enter key event completes
import keyboard

def on_enter_press(event):
# Block the enter key to stop the default action
keyboard.block_key('enter')

# Get the current contents of the input buffer
current_text = keyboard.get_typed_strings(keyboard._pressed_events)

# Write the emoji sequence
keyboard.write("")

# Simulate pressing Enter
keyboard.send("enter")

# Unblock the enter key
keyboard.unblock_key('enter')

# Hook the Enter key
keyboard.hook_key("enter", on_enter_press)

# Wait for the escape key to exit the script
keyboard.wait("esc")

Thanks
